# StyleCop-4.7.35.0 does not integrate with VS2012 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stylecop

I noticed that the latest StyleCop version (4.7.35.0) does not integrate with VS2012 RTM. It doesn't show after install.

Is a release planned for VS2012 RTM very soon?

Comment: This was the wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: Why Bernard ? This is programming related

Comment: You should have asked this to the maintainers of the StyleCop project located [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com). Only they can tell you for certain.

Comment: Since later versions of StyleCop supports the released VS2012 this can be closed